# Git: Import Git Index to non-git directory

Tags: git

Let's pretend I have a project directory that isn't a git repository. This project is open source, and it is listed on github. I'd like to update my project directory to the latest repository structure. I could do this by copying the repo's **.git/** to my directory, followed by a

```
git reset --hard
```

Which would then change the preexisting working directory to match the github repository. Normally, I'd just start fresh by cloning the github repo, but in this case may I have deployment-specific files I'd like keep(which are listed in .gitignore).

I wonder, is there an better way to do this besides manually copying the git index to non-git directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to do this is to have a script that does the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
export GIT_DIR=/srv/git/whatever.git
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/where/to/deploy/
git checkout -f
```

People often use this in a `post-receive` hook in a bare repository, so that you can deploy a new version of the application just by pushing to that repository.

Comment: A short and easy solution. Thanks!